# C# Unable to update excel file (shared or unshared) using oledb

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, shared, overwrite

trying to update excel file using oledb in C#.

I need the program to be able update one column in that file even when other users have this excel file opened.

- If I set the file as nonshared, I open the file in my Excel first and then execute the program. The program is able to update some cells in the required column, but some not, reporting "The Microsoft Office Access database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time" . The cell changes, the program is able to update, are reflected in my Excel instantly after program finishes. So conclusion is, that some, but not all, cells can be updated (I am sure no one is updating them).
- If I set the excel file to shared, I can update all cells in the column without error (checked updated data in the file), but in my Excel the cells are not changed and if I save the file in my excel afterwards, the changes made by the program are overwritten with the old values. So this does not work at all.

So no method is successfull. Please advice :(.

Write part of the c# program:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        var constring = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;Importmixedtypes=text;typeguessrows=0;HDR=YES\"", "c:\\file.xlsx");
        var con = new OleDbConnection(constring);
        try
        {
            var sql = "UPDATE [Direct shipment$] SET [TNT Tracking No] = \'" + txtTracking.Text + "\' WHERE [DS Number] = "+ txtRMA.Text;
            con.Open();
            myCommand.Connection = con;
            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I was probably able to get it working with the the non-shared excel file by re-setting all cells format in the excel file. So it seems like some internal excel bug in the xlsx file. So far it seems it works in that case. I do not understand, how it can write to any non shared excel file, which is already open, but OK :) Never got it to work with shared file so far though.